# How to have sigma of something while plotting?

Tags: r, plot, mosaic-plot

I am using `plotFun` function of `mosaic` package in R. I am trying to plot a 3D plot. Following is my code snippet:

```
plotFun(2*l*(w/log(beta*kspill*lambda^2+(1+(w/x-w)/10)*(lambda^2*5+lambda^1*5+1))+(w/x-w)/log((1+((w/x-w)/10)^1)*(lambda^2*5+lambda^1*5+1))) ~ x  & lambda ,
        x.lim=range(0.8,1), lambda.lim=range(1,3),
        l=60,w=40,kspill=10,f=1,beta=0.5,surface=TRUE)
```

This is working fine. Now suppose I want to fix `lambda` and introduce a new variable `t` such that if `t=2` we get `lambda^2*5+lambda^1*5+1` as in the above case. If `t=3` we get `lambda^3*5+lambda^2*5+lambda^1*5+1` and so on. So now I have `t.lim=range(1,3)` for a fixed lambda :

```
plotFun(2*l*(w/log(beta*kspill*lambda^2+(1+(w/x-w)/10)*("depends on t"))+(w/x-w)/log((1+((w/x-w)/10)^1)*("depends on t"))) ~ x  & lambda ,
        x.lim=range(0.8,1), t.lim=range(0.5,1),
        l=60,w=40,kspill=10,f=1,beta=0.5,lambda=1,surface=TRUE)
```

What to write in the "depends on t" part above. I guess we can't put a `for` loop there to calculate 5* {summation i=0 to i=t}lambda<sup>i</sup>. How to go about doing this?

Comment: A data example, perhaps using one of the installed datasets, followed by further edits might reduce the amount of guesswork that would be needed in the current q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your "depends on t" with

`depends_on_t <- makeFun(5 * sum(lambda^(1:round(t))) + 1 ~ t + lambda, lambda = 1)`

But you still have some issues to resolve:

1) Your `plotFun()` command is creating a plot using `x` and `lambda`, but I'm guessing you meant `x` and `t`.

2) `t` can only be an integer if you are going to use it in a sum of the type you are suggesting.  But you are creating a plot that assumes continuous variables for the axes.  I inserted `round(t)` as one way to move from real values to integer values before computing the sum.  The makes the function work for non-integer values, but it might not be what you really want.

Finally, some additional suggestions:

3) `x & lambda` should be replaced with `x + lambda`.  The use of `&` here dates back to the very early days of the `mosaic` package, and although it is still supported (I think, we don't really test for it anymore), we prefer `x + lambda`.

4) I recommend separating out the definition of your function from the `plotFun()` command.  You can use `mosaic::makeFun()` as illustrated above, or the usual `function()` to define your function and whatever default values you want for its arguments.  Then you can do sanity checks on the function, or use it in multiple plots rather than including all of the function's definition in each plot.

5) Using spaces and returns would make your code much more readable.  (As would simplifying your example to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue you are asking about.)

6) I think you might want

`depends_on_t <- makeFun(5 * sum(lambda^(0:round(t)))  ~ t + lambda, lambda = 1)`

rather than the formula as you describe it, but without more context, I can't really know.